# execute external script when the last option value selected

Tags: jquery, external-script

I working on little page where user have to select 4 thing, once the last option value is selected then I want to execute external script like to load overly player:

```
<script scr="video.js" async="true" callback="myFunction()"></script>
```

Tried to use `$.getScript` but it's not working as I wanted.
This is part of the code where I tried to add:

```
$("select").change(function(){
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
        var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
        if(optionValue){
            $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
            $("." + optionValue).show();

        } else{
            $(".box").hide();
        }
    });
}).change();
```

Thanks for help and understanding,
Bart

Comment: where is the select options?

Answer (score 0):

Topic can be closed, below you can check how I made it working

```
    $("select").change(function(){
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
        var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
        if(optionValue){
            $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
            $("." + optionValue).show(function(){
                var includes = $('[data-include]');
                jQuery.each(includes, function(){
                  var file = 'views/' + $(this).data('include') + '.html';
                  $(this).load(file);
                });
              });
        } else{
            $(".box").hide();
        }
    });
}).change();
```